# How to return fields of both related models in a Django ManyToMany relation?

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I have two models:

```py
class P(mdoels.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=False,max_length=120)
    ...

class F(mdoels.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=False,max_length=120)
    ...
    p = models.ManyToManyField(P)
```

I need a query like this:

```sql
SELECT p.name, f.name
FROM f
JOIN f_p ON f.id = f_p.f_id
JOIN p ON p.id= f_p.p_id
```

I can use the `f.objects.filter()`, but it doesn't returns the fields of `p` and I need just to show a list with the both names.

In `psql` the query works like I need. How can I do this in Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `values_list` [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

```py
F.objects.values_list('name', 'p__name')
```

Comment: This solution works. In my code I used `P.objects.values()`. Thaks for it.

Comment: @EduardoStefanello click upvote if it was useful for you

Answer (score 0):

Use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

```py
F.objects.filter(...).prefetch_related('p')
```

Comment: I've tried this, but I couldn't access the fields of `P` in result `QuerySet`